# Is there any way to hide the params from the query string in react routing?

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router-v4, react-router-dom, react-routing

Is there any way to remove the query string from the url in react application?

`this.history.push('component/:id')`

I want id to be removed from the browser url while navigation.

Answer (score 5):

The `Redirect` and `Link` components both have an overloaded `to` prop which can either be the string like you displayed above or an object with the following keys: `pathname`, `search`, `hash`, `state`. So your `Link` can become something like

```
<Link to={pathname: '/component', state: {id: '#id'}} />
```

However, keep in mind that you will have to modify your Route to no longer require an id as a urlParameter and instead in your component you should use `this.props.location.state.id` to access the variable.

Answer (score 0):

This is only suggestion: if you are using redux then save your id: in reducer
then push any dummy string into your URL it will appear

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
class example extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.match.params.id != 'dummy-string') {
      this.props.saveId(this.props.match.params.id);
      this.props.history.push('/component/dummy-string');
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div >
        <h1>Example</h1>
        {this.props.id ? 
          <div>this.props.id</div>
          :null}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  id: state.reducer1.id
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  saveId: (id) => dispatch({ type: 'SAVE_ID',payload:id })
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(example);
```